# MySQL select rows where its columns sum equal value

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have following tables:

A:

```
+----+-----------+-------+----------+
| ID | PaymentID | Price | Quantity |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |   128 |        1 |
|  2 |         2 |    10 |        2 |
|  3 |         2 |    11 |        1 |
|  4 |         3 |   100 |        2 |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+
```

B:

```
+-----------+------------+
| PaymentID | TotalPrice |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |        128 |
|         2 |         31 |
|         3 |        201 |
+-----------+------------+
```

And query:

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.PaymentID = a.PaymentID
WHERE b.TotalPrice = (a.Price * a.Quantity)
```

It works fine when a.PaymentID is unique, but some transactions in table A are separated and paid (table B) together. Query above return a.ID = 1 but I need to return a.ID = 1,2,3.

```
a.PaymentID(1): 128 * 1 = 128 MATCH
a.PaymentID(2): 10 * 2 + 11 * 1 = 31 MATCH
a.PaymentID(3): 100 * 2 = 200 NOT MATCH
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b261/1/0)

Comment: Why  you `need to return a.ID = 1,2,3.` What is your expected output?

Comment: Why you expect ID =3? here totalprice is not equals price * quantity?

Comment: Why do you need table B? You need to maintain it to be correct. You can retrieve it via simple SQL. SELECT PaymentID, sum(Price*Quantity) FROM A WHERE PaymentID = 2 GROUP BY PaymentID

Comment: Transactions in table A is separated (PaymentID = 2) => 10*2 + 11*1 = 31 from table B. Table A is list of transactions and table B is generated from bank account and I need to return transactions that match received payments.

Comment: Incidentally, this would render as an INNER JOIN.

Comment: But it still doesn't work if a.PaymentID is separated in two rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to join sum of Price and amount from table a to table b along with the PaymentId, and using it onto a joining clause which would be calculated per row based not on aggregate based.
You may need to first find the aggregate part and then join something as

```
select
a.ID
from a 
left join (
  select sum(Price*Quantity) as tot,PaymentID 
  from a group by PaymentID
)x on x.PaymentID = a.PaymentID
join b on b.PaymentID = a.PaymentID and x.tot = b.TotalPrice
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b261/45

Answer (score 3):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.totalprice
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.PaymentID = a.PaymentID
group by b.paymentID
having TotalPrice = sum(a.Price * a.Quantity)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b261/14)

UPDATE: After clarification:

```
select a.id from a where paymentId in(
  select paymentID from(
SELECT a.paymentID as paymentID, b.totalprice
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.PaymentID = a.PaymentID
group by b.paymentID
having TotalPrice = sum(a.Price * a.Quantity)) as c )
```

Comment: It works now. But @Abhik solution seems better for my needs. Anyway thank you for your patience.